# How to show that these sets are algebraic sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This question was asked in my class of Algebraic geometry and I was not able to solve this question.

Question : Show that $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{A}^n (K)$ are algebraic sets.

Attempt: If $\emptyset$  is an algebraic set , then there exists a set S such that $V(S)= ${$ x\in \mathbb{A}^n (K) $ for every $P\in S $ such that P(x)=0}, here P is always a polynomial.

If I take $S=\mathbb{N}$ and polynomial equals $x^n+y^n - z^n=0$, then I think I have proved that $\phi$ is algebraic. Is my proof right? I think one error is that $\mathbb{N}$ is not a field.

But in the case of n degrees I was not able to find such a set which will work for $\mathbb{A}^n (K)$  and a field so how should I find such equations in both cases?

Please help!

Comment: what are the algebraic sets $V(S)$ associated with $S=\{0\}$ and $S=\{1\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint given in the comments is spot on. Remember you're looking to realize $\mathbb A^n(K)$ and $\emptyset$ as the vanishing sets of a collection of polynomials.

So what happens if you consider the set $S = \{1\}$, where this is the constant polynomial $p(x) = 1$? This polynomial doesn't vanish anywhere, so what is $V(S)$ in this case?

Similarly, if $S = \{0\}$ i.e. the zero polynomial $p(x) = 0$ what happens? In this case, the polynomial vanishes for all $x \in \mathbb A^n(K)$. So what is $V(S)$ here?